# How to navigate from Home screen to Login screen in a nested navigation ? React Navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I'm trying to improve my navigation in my React Native project using React Navigation. I would like to know how to navigate through a nested navigator from Home to Login screen.

navigation.ts

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  AuthorizedTabStack: BottomTabScreenProps<AuthorizedTabNavigationList>;
  AuthorizedModalStack: NavigatorScreenParams<AuthorizedModalList>;
  UnauthorizedStack: NavigatorScreenParams<UnauthorizedStackList>;
};

export type AuthorizedTabNavigationList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Planner: undefined;
};

export type AuthorizedModalList = {
  InputModal: undefined;
};

export type UnauthorizedStackList = {
  Login: undefined;
};
```

In my MainNavigator.tsx, I've implemented this...

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {auth.currentUser ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="AuthorizedTabStack" component={TabNavigation} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="AuthorizedModalStack"
              component={ModalNavigation}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="UnauthorizedStack"
            component={UnauthorizedStack}
          />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

The UnauthorizedStackList is basically a StackNavigator

```
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

I tried using this and there is an error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"UnauthorizedStack","params":{"screen":"Login"}} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'UnauthorizedStack'?

```
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProps>();

  const handlePressLogOut = () => {
    logOut()
    navigation.navigate('UnauthorizedStack', { screen: 'Login' });
  };
```

Please let me know if there are better practices on nested navigator or anything else in the code as well. I would like to learn more!

Answer (score 2):

Your `navigation.navigate(...)` is called before auth state updates, because changing state is not happening right away. You cannot navigate to a screen, that is not rendered.

A few notes about your code:

- you don't have to call `navigation.navigate(...)` after logging out, because you are conditionally rendering screens with `auth.currentUser`, so `UnauthorizedStack` will be rendered right after `logOut()`,
- if `Login` screen is the only screen in your stack, probably there is no need for using stack,

Comment: Could I also ask you how to navigate from Home to InputModal with useNavigation with typescript?

Comment: If there is the `auth.currentUser`, your `UnauthorizedStack` is not rendered, so you are not able to navigate to it. If you want to do that, you have to change your rendering logic. What's the use case for that navigation?

Comment: Ah.. ok it must get rendered to be able to navigate. I currently has user object (from Firebase) and Firebase's auth function to check for the conditional rendering. Thanks for the answer!